# What exactly is .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

Don't get me wrong, I've read about it. But I dont exactly understand what it is. In a previous thread I talked about wanting to learn more GUI based stuff. C# and (WPF or w/e it's called) seemed to be the best option for a newbie. But then people mentioned .net. Is that like a new language?

How exactly does it integrate with C# and WPF and such?

Also completely off topic. Is C# even being used much anymore? Or has it kind of been going downhill?

Comment: WPF is part of the .net framework, and C# is a language targeting .net. .net itself consists of a runtime and a library.

Comment: An old article, but it stems from the time when .Net was lost and confused in marketing mumbo jumbo: http://arstechnica.com/paedia/n/net/net-1.html

Comment: This is why I don't assume any kind of working knowledge just because somebody has a computer science degree. It blows my mind that a school could produce a graudate in *2010* who has never heard of .Net.

Comment: @meagar - you should have seen some of the graduates from mine. :(

Comment: U can hear of .net but not know how or what it constitues.

Comment: .Net is basically a ecosystem. it consist of 
1. languages: C#V, B, F# 
2. Runtime: Core CLR(like JVM for Java)
3. Libraries: BCL,OSS ..

Answer (score 5):

.net is a framework and NO C# is moving forward.

Have a loo at [.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)

> The Microsoft .NET Framework is a
>   software framework for Microsoft
>   Windows operating systems. It includes
>   a large library, and it supports
>   several programming languages which
>   allows language interoperability (each
>   language can utilize code written in
>   other languages.) The .NET library is
>   available to all the programming
>   languages that .NET supports.
>
> The framework's Base Class Library
>   provides user interface, data access,
>   database connectivity, cryptography,
>   web application development, numeric
>   algorithms, and network
>   communications. The class library is
>   used by programmers, who combine it
>   with their own code to produce
>   applications.
>
> Programs written for the .NET
>   Framework execute in a software (as
>   contrasted to hardware) environment,
>   known as the Common Language Runtime
>   (CLR). The CLR is an application
>   virtual machine so that programmers
>   need not consider the capabilities of
>   the specific CPU that will execute the
>   program. The CLR also provides other
>   important services such as security,
>   memory management, and exception
>   handling. The class library and the
>   CLR together constitute the .NET
>   Framework.

Comment: Feed them cement, so theire bellies stay full... X-)

Comment: How am I trolling? Im actually wanting to know.....about this stuff

Comment: In your question you say "Is C# even being used much any more? Or has it kind of been going downhill?" Given that C# has been very much improved upon in the last 2-3 years and is much much better than it was when it came out originally the comment seems designed to inflame rather than illicit information.

Comment: Or be a lame attempt at a rep grab

Comment: Im only asking about C#'s future because IM interested in it. Plus rep is nice, but I could care less about awards and such, im only on this site for information

Answer (score 1):

.NET is a platform for applications. It includes a runtime environment, a large class library (which includes WPF) and it supports several different languages such as C#, VB.NET and F#.

C# is still actively being developed. Version 4.0 of the language specification was recently release, and a [community tech preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) of upcoming features for version 5.0 was released a few month after, so it is far from dead.